# Remove ripple from regulated voltage

Tags: voltage-regulator, dc-motor

I'm trying to hook up a voltage regulator (TI TLV1117) to a power source where an electric motor is also connected. The motor draws about 5A at 15V. There is a free-wheel diode across the motor.

Here is the schematic:

[image: schematics]

Measuring V+, I would have expected it to be more or less constant 3.3V, but there are spikes well over 5V when turning on the motor.

Scope screen dump:

[image: scope]

The low pass filter at the input (R3 = 2k2) improved it quite a bit, but the peak values are still way too high and noise is unacceptable. How can I go about to remove the ripple I get when turning on the motor?

Comment: Can you show the schematic where and how the motor is connected? How's your layout? What about ceramic decoupling capacitors on the 3.3 V rail?

Comment: 2.2k with 220uF is a pretty serious filter. You could add more capacitance or more resistance or multiple stages of filtration. There is also some possibility that the noise you are seeing is induced into the oscilloscope probe meaning that it is not "real." It is kind of hard to put a 5V spike onto a 100uF cap.

Comment: Breadboard only so far. The freewheel diode is soldered directly to the motor. The 15V rail is provided by a switching PSU. There are no ceramic capacitors om the 3.3V. Any suggestions on values?

Comment: @mkeith Any suggestions on how to suppress any noise induced into the probe? I'm very much a beginner, so I'm in at the deep end here.

Comment: Noise in the probe often results from the details of the connection of the probe ground lead. When working with substantial currents, such as motor currents, you need to be aware of where the currents flow, and whether there is a chance of currents flowing through your probe ground connection. This can be made worse by the fact that probe ground is connected to mains earth. Proper probing must take such things into account.